# How to check the strength of a password in C++ using bool functions

Tags: c++, passwords, boolean, c-strings

Working on an exercise for my class. My teacher wants us to work with C-string, not the string class. We must use bool functions and C-string commands to determine if a password is strong enough. I think I'm close to being done but I must have some error somewhere? Here's what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

bool checklength(char[]);
bool checkdigit(char[]);
bool checklower(char[]);
bool checkupper(char[]);
bool checkspecial(char[]);

int main()
{
char pwdstr[20];

std::cout << "Enter your password\n";
std::cin >> pwdstr;

if (checklength(pwdstr) &&
    checkdigit(pwdstr) &&
    checklower(pwdstr) &&
    checkupper(pwdstr) &&
    checkspecial(pwdstr))
{
    std::cout << "Your password is strong.\n";
}

else
{
    std::cout << "Your password is too weak!\n";
}
}

bool checklength(char p[])
{
int i;
int len = strlen(p);

for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
{
    if (isalnum(p[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

if (i < 6)
{
    std::cout << "Your password must be at least 6 characters 
long.\n";
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}

bool checkdigit(char p[])
{
int i;
int len = strlen(p);

for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
{
    if (isdigit(p[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

if (i < 1)
{
    std::cout << "Your password must have at least 1 digit in 
it.\n";
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}

bool checklower(char p[])
{
int i;
int len = strlen(p);

for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
{
    if (islower(p[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

if (i < 1)
{
    std::cout << "Your password must have at least 1 lower case 
letter in it.\n";
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}

bool checkupper(char p[])
{
int i;
int len = strlen(p);

for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
{
    if (isupper(p[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

if (i < 1)
{
    std::cout << "Your password must have at least 1 upper case 
letter in it.\n";
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}

bool checkspecial(char p[])
{
int i;
int len = strlen(p);

for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
{
    if (ispunct(p[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

if (i < 1)
{
    std::cout << "Your password must have at least 1 special 
character in it.\n";
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

My current output before I added the descriptions of what went wrong before returning false was that everything was correct for some reason. Now everything I try says that I'm failing at the checklength function, that the password is too short.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your loops are wrong, you're confusing the index of the character you are testing, with the count of the number of characters that have passed the test, you need separate variables for this. Plus you have an out by error on the length of the length of the string, you had `len - 1` instead of `len`.
So this

```
bool checklength(char p[])
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(p);

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1;)
    {
        if (isalnum(p[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (i < 6)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password must be at least 6 characters long.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

should be this

```
bool checklength(char p[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen(p);        
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isalnum(p[i]))
            count++;
    }
    if (count < 6)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password must be at least 6 characters long.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions could be simplified quite a bit with STL algorithms. e.g. `checklength` could be:

```
bool checklength(char p[])
{
  return std::count_if(p, p + strlen(p), [](unsigned char c) {
                        return std::isalnum(c); 
                       }) >= 6;
}
```

and you could do similar things for the other functions.